# can not use signalr sample for a console application

Tags: asp.net, console-application, signalr

i was trying signalR hubs trough their sample at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs.

i managed to create an mvc 4 asp.net app using their sample for asp.net, BUT when i try to debug the console app program :

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Connect to the service
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/5623");

        // Create a proxy to the chat service
        var chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chat");

        // Print the message when it comes in
        chat.On("addMessage", message => Console.WriteLine(message));

        // Start the connection
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

        string line = null;
        while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Send a message to the server
            chat.Invoke("Send", line).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

it send me an exception at *hubConnection.Start().Wait();* saying *{"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."}*.

i think it has something to do with the `http://localhost/5623`, i tried `http://localhost/5623/Home` and `http://localhost/5623/Home/Chat` i got *{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}* error instead.

How can i solve this please.

Thank you.

Comment: 500 means the problem is with the server.  Can you attach a debugger to the server and see what the problem is?

Comment: how can i debug two projects at the same time. the server code lives in the asp.net app wich is working just fine, i can open two browser and start chatting. i have a probleme only with the console app :(

Comment: If you are using VS, you can open 2 instances and debug the client and server.  Or you can just attach to the server.  The server is returning an error (a client error would be in the 400 range).

Comment: seriously i dont know how to debug console app and asp.net app in the same time, i have VS 2012 installed.
and yes i agree with you, 500 error comes from the server but why the asp.net app is working fine ???

Comment: i manage to debug both server and client app. the server is just working fine :( any help please ?

Comment: anyone ca help me please ???

Comment: I finally get this working. the `var chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chat");` was the probleme. By adding `[HubName("chat")]` to my hub in the server side the console app is working now fine.

I hope this can help.

Comment: I see you have http://localhost/5623, is your iis application's name 5623 or is that supposed to be a port number?